# Maintaining Connection using WebSockets

Tags: javascript, c#, websocket

I have a JavaScript/html web socket client.  It receives images from my server quite frequently.  I am hosting my web socket server in a C# console application.

The longest my client has to wait for an image is 10 seconds.

Should I also be sending 'keep-alive' packets from my client (JavaScript) to my Server or is the fact that it receives regular data packets from my server enough?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send ping messages from the server, and the client will answer with a pong message. It is part of the WebSocket protocol, not sure if your server implementation supports it. However, from the client you have no way to know if you got a ping message in while, so the client may be let hanging there.

Or you can do it at application level using your own messages. Basically create a "ping" message in JSON and send it regularly from the client to the server, then if you do not get a response in X time, reconnect.

If you don´t, the only problem is that the connection maybe [half-open](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html), and your client may be hanging there waiting for a image that will never come.

Cheers.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I am using SuperSocket 1.6.  What I am experiencing is that my server wants to send an image but the client has disconnected. However, the onClose and onError events are not being fired in my JavaScript. I am trying to establish whether this because of the SuperSocket framework i am using or whether I should be sending a PING to my server every now now then,

Comment: Additionally, if I do send a PING from Client to Server AND my server is sending an image at the same time as to whether this will cause the image to be missed or/and the connection to drop (for some reason :) )

Comment: Well that is what half-connections do. They do not trigger any event, they are just zombies :) Probably sending a ping message from client to server is the best here, since the client won´t notice the connection is half-open until it try to send anything.

Comment: The connection is full-duplex, it won´t break an image in course. The only problem is that if the image is to big and the timeout for your ping messages to small, the ping message will queue until the image is fully sent. This is why protocol pings are better, because control frames can be interleaved with ata. Additionally, if you want a WebSocket server in C# with ping support you can use mine: http://vtortola.github.io/WebSocketListener/ It may be helpful to also have connections checks from the server.

Comment: Yes, I just educated myself with that link you kindly included in your answer. I have just checked and the Server Side is configured for keep-alives very 60 seconds so, I conclude from all this I need a keep alive from the Client as well. But, a side thought here,if my server is sending images every 10 seconds then it will not need a keep alive is that correct. And if that is so will there be a slight performance improvement if I disabled Keep-Alives from the server side?

Comment: Keep-alives are probably very small messages and the WebSocket protocol is ver minimalist, so it won´t be a problem. If you are sending an image each 10 seconds, you can put some logic in your client that says "if you do not get an image in 20 seconds, reconnect" for example.